# Will numpy.roots() ever return n different floats when a polynomial only has <n unique (exact) roots?

Tags: numpy, scipy

I think the title says it all, but just to be specific, say I have some list of numbers named "coeffs".  Assuming the polynomial with said coefficients has exactly k unique roots, will the following code ever set number_of_unique_roots  to be a number greater than k?

```
import numpy as np
number_of_unique_roots = len(set(np.roots(coeffs)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
>>> len(set(numpy.roots([1, 6, 9])))
2
>>> numpy.roots([1, 6, 9])
array([-3. +3.72529030e-08j, -3. -3.72529030e-08j])
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, the perturbation `f(x)+eps·g(x)` of a polynomial `f(x)` with a k-fold root will in general have unique roots and the k-fold root separates into a nearly symmetric star with k vertices around the original k-fold root with a distance proportional to `eps^(1/k)`.

The numerical evaluation of a polynomial (in 64bit `doubles`) comes with cancelation errors, especially close to a root. This can be interpreted a perturbation with `eps=1e-16`. Thus, as in to other answer, a double root splits into two roots with a distance of magnitude `1e-8` and the original root in the middle. A 4-fold root would lead to a square or diamond formation of size `~1e-4` etc.